# Cant load font using the global styles in styled components

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, fonts, styled-components

I would like to use Inter as a global font for entire application. I'm using React, Typescript and Styled component. The font is downloaded from fontsquirrel service and is loaded in globalStyles file.

On Firefox I have following error. I don't think that the files are somehow corrupted.

```sh
downloadable font: rejected by sanitizer (font-family: "Inter" style:normal weight:400 stretch:100 src index:0) source: http://localhost:3000/fonts/Inter-Regular.ttf
```

On Chrome

```sh
Failed to decode downloaded font: http://localhost:3000/fonts/Inter-Regular.ttf
```

Global styles file which is used in root react file.

```js
import { createGlobalStyle } from 'styled-components';

export const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle`
  @font-face {
     font-family: 'Inter';
     src: url('../fonts/Inter-Bold.ttf') format("truetype");
  }
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'Inter';
     src: url('../fonts/Inter-Medium.ttf') format("truetype");
  }
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'Inter';
     src: url('../fonts/Inter-Regular.ttf') format("truetype");

  }
  body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Inter', -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', 'Roboto', 'Oxygen', 'Ubuntu', 'Cantarell', 'Fira Sans',
    'Droid Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  }
`;
```